# How to programmatically login into an aspx(IIS) Site

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I'm searching for a way, to login programmatically into a aspx-based (with ending /login.aspx) site.
The programm should work like my programm to login into a php-based site:

```
static String loginurl = "";
static String secondUrl = "";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String menuInput;
        String password;
        String username;
        String storagePath;
        bool quit = true;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu of FileDownloader:");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Downloadfile");
            Console.WriteLine("q: Quit FileDownloader");

            menuInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if(menuInput.Equals("1"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is your username: ");
                username = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("What is your password: ");
                password = ReadPassword();
                //Console.WriteLine("Where should the file be saved: ");
                storagePath = "path..."; //or Console.ReadLine();
                if (!Directory.Exists(storagePath))
                {
                    String createFlag;
                    Console.WriteLine("The path does not exist.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Should this be created now? [y/n]");
                    createFlag = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (createFlag.Equals("y"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("path " + storagePath + " will be created" );
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(storagePath);
                        Console.WriteLine("path is created");
                        DownloadFile(username, password, storagePath);
                    }
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download will be canceled");
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                } else
                {
                    DownloadFile(username, password, storagePath);
                }



            }
            else if (menuInput.Equals("q"))
            {
                quit = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("input wrong");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.Clear();
            }

        } while (quit);
        Environment.Exit(0);

    }
    //Source from here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/password-in-c-sharp-console-application
    public static string ReadPassword()
    {
        string password = "";
        ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
        while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            if (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                password += info.KeyChar;
            }
            else if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                {
                    // remove one character from the list of password characters
                    password = password.Substring(0, password.Length - 1);
                    // get the location of the cursor
                    int pos = Console.CursorLeft;
                    // move the cursor to the left by one character
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(pos - 1, Console.CursorTop);
                    // replace it with space
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    // move the cursor to the left by one character again
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(pos - 1, Console.CursorTop);
                }
            }
            info = Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        // add a new line because user pressed enter at the end of their password
        Console.WriteLine();
        return password;
    }

        public static bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, 
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, 
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, 
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static void DownloadFile(String username, String password, String storagePath)
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginurl);
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        string cookieName = null;

        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

        if (cookieName != null)
            container.Add(new Cookie(cookieName, username, "/", new Uri(loginurl).Host));

        request.CookieContainer = container;

        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  Modify this line accordingly
        string postData = String.Format("tbUsername={0}&tbPassword={1}", username, password);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
            new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //easy mechanism to detect if authentication failed.
        if (responseFromServer.Contains("Sie sind nicht angemeldet."))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed\nThe Application will be closed!");
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }


        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(secondUrl);
        request.CookieContainer = container;

        response = request.GetResponse();


        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Start to write pdf");
        Console.WriteLine();

        /*StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);*/
        Thread t = new Thread(Progress);
        t.Start();

        CreatePDF(response, storagePath);

        t.Abort();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Finished to write pdf");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.Clear();
    }
    private static void Progress()
    {
        while(true)
        {

            Console.Write("#");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

    }

   private static void CreatePDF(WebResponse response, String storagePath)
    {
        //writes stream to a PDF file
        String[] tmp = secondUrl.Split('=');
        String filename = tmp[1]+"tmp";
        if (!filename.Contains(".pdf"))
        {
            filename += ".pdf";
        }
        using (var streamFile = File.Create(storagePath + filename))
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(streamFile);
    }

    private static String getFileName()
    {
        int pos = secondUrl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        return secondUrl.Substring(pos, secondUrl.Length - pos);
    }
```

Like you see, first you get asked about your username and your password.
If i'm logged in, it should downlaod a pdf-file, but that have to come a bit later. The big Problem ist, that I just can't find the right way to solve this login.
The code is working for php perfectly.

If you run this code on the aspx-based site and try to download the pdf, you will get the site-content from the login.

Comment: ntlm or text based login?

Comment: Websites are under no obligation to have a login that works nicely for this type of usage. It sounds like you should be using an API (perhaps web-based), not a website designed for a browser. Do you own the website you're hitting? If you do: then expose an API. If you don't: stop doing this.

Comment: @BugFinder sorry, can't answer this question, what's the difference ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've got a specific site for that, and it should work there.

Comment: if you use text based you can do http://user:password@url .. the other you have to use network credential sending

Comment: @MarcGravell to answer the edit: I'm not the owner, but the company i'm working for. And I have to write a programm that automate some processes (trainee), so it's okey. But i don't have access to everything and even less informations.

Comment: @BugFinder if it helps, it's a webapplication to get access to files from an database. But you can only open the webapplication if you are in the vpn.

Comment: @Peeety sadly no that doesnt help - you need to work out what the authentication method is.

Comment: @BugFinder how can I find out if its ntlm or text based ?

Comment: a number of options come to mind, ask the man who made it, if you login with your windows login (well then duh), try logging in like I suggested above...

Comment: @BugFinder To login, I have to write my username and my password in a textbox and press a login-button, so i think it sounds like text-based, isn't it ?

Comment: Well given I told you how that could work if it truly is text based then you would have an answer, if its not then its purely site based and logins maybe stored in a database.. in which case you have a lot of hard work ahead, and beyond the SO scope.

Comment: @BugFinder so, if I try like testUser:TestPw@testurl/login.aspx and it says ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, I have a problem ? D:

Comment: is testurl the hostname?